# Volume of a Steinmetz-like solid

Tags: integration, volume, solid-geometry

Consider three cylinders intersecting with a unit cube.  Their intersection within the unit cube produces a 3-sided solid with a volume of about .386.

[image]

One cylinder has center axis (0,0,1) to (0,1,1) with unit radius, the others are rotations.

What is an exact solution for the volume?

Comment: https://www.physicsforums.com/threads/volume-of-3-intersecting-cylinders.315248/ but the result for $R=1$ doesn't coincide with yours

Comment: The structure Jean Marie points to has three intersecting axes.  In the figure I'm asking about, the axes do not intersect.

Comment: I should have paid more attention...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert the volume integral to a surface integral:
$$\int_D dV = \frac 1 3 \int_{\partial D} \mathbf r \cdot d\mathbf S.$$
Parametrize one piece of the surface as $(x, y, z) = (1 + \cos t, \sin t, z)$. The $(t, z)$ domain will be $\pi/2 < t < \pi, \,f(t) < z < g(t)$, where $f$ and $g$ are found from the equations of the other two cylinders. The integrals over the other two pieces are the same due to symmetry. This gives
$$V = \int_{\pi/2}^\pi \left(
  \sqrt {(2 - \sin t) \sin t} + \sqrt {-(2 + \cos t) \cos t} - 1
 \right) (1 + \cos t) \,dt = \\
\frac {15} 2 E {\left( \frac 1 9 \right)} -
6 K {\left( \frac 1 9 \right)} -\frac {3 \pi} 4 + 1,$$
with the elliptic integrals given in the parameter notation.